# How to increment version number under certain requirements in PHP

Tags: php, increment

I would like to increment version number `$numero1 = "1.0.1"` by the following ruleset.

1. Increment the last number (the one after the second period).
2. If the incremented number is greater than 9 then set to 0 and increment the second number.
3. If the second number is also greater than 9 (after incrementing) then set to 0 and increment the first number.

So what I did is `$numerosumado = $numero1 + 1` but it's not working because of the dots. So my question is how do I do it?

Comment: How many numbers were you taught about in school that were shown with two dots (or decimal points)? That is not a number..... what would you expect to happen when you increase `1.0.1` by `1`? Would you get `2.0.1`, `1.1.1`, `1.1.2`, `2.1.2`?

Comment: I would like it to go from 1.0.1 to 1.0.2 @MarkBaker

Comment: Explode the string on the `.`. add one to the last element of teh resullting array, then implode with a `.` again

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note: This is just one way out of many...

For further explanations see the comments in this working snippet.

```
<?php
$numero1 = "1.9.9";
$numerosumado = explode( ".", $numero1 ); // array( "1", "9", "9" )
if ( ++$numerosumado[2] > 9 ) { // if last incremented number is greater than 9 reset to 0
    $numerosumado[2] = 0;
    if ( ++$numerosumado[1] > 9 ) { // if second incremented number is greater than 9 reset to 0
        $numerosumado[1] = 0;
        ++$numerosumado[0]; // incremented first number
    }
}
$numerosumado = implode( ".", $numerosumado ); // implode array back to string
```

Hint: incrementing a numeric string such as "1" or "0.9" will automatically change the type to integer or float and increment as expected.

---

**Edit:** This solution is a bit more elegant.

```
<?php
$version = "9.9.9";
for ( $new_version = explode( ".", $version ), $i = count( $new_version ) - 1; $i > -1; --$i ) {
    if ( ++$new_version[ $i ] < 10 || !$i ) break; // break execution of the whole for-loop if the incremented number is below 10 or !$i (which means $i == 0, which means we are on the number before the first period)
    $new_version[ $i ] = 0; // otherwise set to 0 and start validation again with next number on the next "for-loop-run"
}
$new_version = implode( ".", $new_version );
```

Comment: awesome but I also want it to go to the next number, for example if it reachs 9 then increment the other numer (1.0.9 to 1.1.0). I'm trying to do something to increment the version of the site @Axel

Comment: @QuinnHumphreys please have a look again - will add some explanations too

Comment: Who's to say that you can't have version `1.3.37` though? The "little" patches might exceed 9 before a greater one is applied. If that's a rule you set, by all means, go for it :-)

Comment: @Qirel it was the author who said so :)

Comment: And which my question was asked to, @Axel :) probably should have tagged!

Comment: @QuinnHumphreys apreciate to help you out :)

Comment: @QuinnHumphreys I'd like to inspire you - if you are interested in a more elegant solution see my updated answer again...

Comment: @Axel just for the recdord. What's the difference between the first solution and the second one? and which one should I use?

Comment: @QuinnHumphreys hmm - I would go with version number 2. version 1 feels like a hack to me. version 2 is way more generic - works with version numbers with variable number of periods ("#", "#.#", "#.#.#", "#.#.#.#.#"...). technically you can take both. but you know: programming is a but more complex as it may seem. my advice is to use the version you actually understand. imagine you have to modify something later. if you don't understand whats going on you cannot modify anything - right? In addition you can keep the other version and start using it as soon as you understand whats going on...

Answer (score 6):

I think this one works smoother without too many if's/loops:

```
$a = '1.9.9';
$a = str_replace('.', '', $a) + 1;
$a = implode('.', str_split($a));
echo $a;
```

Basically convert it to a number, increment then convert it back.

The only drawback is that the first integer has to be `>= 1`. So `0.0.1` won't work. I am assuming it would always be `>= 1.0.0` from what you posted.

Comment: Also don't works for cases where the first number (major version number) `> 9`. For example: `9.9.9` will result in `1.0.0.0`. Anyway +1 for smart thinking...